# How to color text output from Pandas Dataframe in terminal (Linux)?

Tags: python, pandas, linux, terminal, colorama

I want to be able to print data from `data_dict` with different colors based on the positive or negative value with Pandas DataFrame text in a linux terminal.

```
data_dict = {"Key1":[1,-2,3], "Key2":[1,2,-3]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data_dict)
print(df)
```

Is there a way to use `colorama.Fore` or something similar to somehow update the color of different cells as they are printed in the terminal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get a colored `pandas.DataFrame` printed to my macos terminal, I used the following code...

```py
import termcolor
import pandas
# assume `df['foo']` is a `pandas.DataFrame` column with
#     boolean values...
#
df = pandas.DataFrame({'foo': [False]}) # this is a fake df with
                                        # no real data.  Ensure 
                                        # you have a real
                                        # DataFrame stored in 
                                        # df...

# NOTE: there's probably a more idiomatic pandas incantation 
# for what I'm doing here, but this is intended to 
# demonstrate the concept of colorizing `colorized_df['foo']`
colorized_df = None
colored_str_value = ""
colorized_row = []
for original_value in df['foo'].values:
    # casting `original_value` bools as strings to color them red...
    colored_str_value = termcolor.colored(str(original_value), 'red')
    colorized_row.append(colored_str_value)
colorized_df = pandas.DataFrame({'foo': colorized_row})
# Do something here with colorized_df...
```

Now when I print `colorized_df` in the terminal, it renders `colorized_df['foo']` with red text...

As such, `colorized_df` cell values must be **cast as a strings** to color the `DataFrame` contents.  For instance, `df['foo']` has boolean data; those booleans have to be cast as strings in `colorized_df[ foo']` (otherwise the values can't be colored).

For most use-cases, re-casting your original `DataFrame` as string is a non-starter... one possible solution (used in my answer) -> keep two copies of the `DataFrame`... (A) one copy to render as the original `DataFrame` type in `df['foo']`... (B) the other copy to manipulate freely and cast to colorized-strings...

However, you must keep those two `DataFrames` synchronized if you modify `df['foo']`.

Comment: one must also colorize the columns to get a correct column width.
if not they will be wider because of the hidder color codes


`colorized_df.columns = [termcolor.colored(x, 'white', None) for x in colorized_df.columns]`

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a way, here is an example solution:

```
import pandas as pd
from termcolor import colored

data_dict = {"Key1":[1,-2,3], "Key2":[1,2,-3]}

df = colored(pd.DataFrame(data_dict), 'red')
print(df)
```

https://pypi.org/project/termcolor/

Edit:

also if you dont want to use imports

you can define a color and iterate the dic for the key values:

```
red = "\033[1;31m"
blue = "\033[1;34m"
data_dict = {"Key1":[1,-2,3], "Key2":[1,2,-3]}
for key in data_dict.keys () :
    print (red, key, blue, data_dict[key])
```

then you just put your condition on the key for the color

Comment: Your second answer works, but doesn't incorporate the DataFrame aspect of the question. Your first answer colors the entire DataFrame (keys and values). I am looking for a solution that only colors the values based on the condition of positive or negative.

Comment: This only colors the whole dataframe with the same color

Comment: if only you know how to program you could change a little the implementation to work for what you want to...

Comment: @JoshCrouse, my answer explains what is required... https://stackoverflow.com/a/75777234/667301

Comment: @Cayman, One, I don't generally work with dataframes so it's relatively foreign to me. Two, yeah, I could probably adapt your solution with a simple for loop, but that's a bit primitive, restrictive, isn't explained very well at all, and you're original answer doesn't answer my question to my satisfaction.